# Sets weird behavior in JS

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to filter some Arrays for unique objects using Sets however I faced a very weird bug (or maybe it is just my misunderstanding of JS). Here is the code snippet.

```
let arr = [
  { type: 'qweqwe', power: 333 },
  { type: 'qweqwe', power: 333 },
  { type: 'qweqwe', power: 333 },
];

let obj = { type: 'qweqwe', power: 333 };
const sameArr= [obj, obj, obj];
```

To my understanding, those are exactly the same arrays however let's try to create a Set for each of the arrays.

```
let arrSet = new Set(arr)
let sameArrSet = new Set(sameArr)
console.log(arrSet)
console.log(sameArrSet)
```

The first log returns Set(3) (doesn't filter unique)
The second log return Set(1) (only unique)

I've tried the same for bigger arrays and the result is the same.

I'd be really grateful if someone could explain this to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two objects in a Set are still different, as `{ a: true } !== { a: true }` (example values)

You cannot use a Set to de-duplicate an array of *objects*. The second works due to the fact that they all point to the same memory location.

```js
let obj1 = { a: true }
let obj2 = { a: true }

let obj1ref = obj1;

console.log(obj1 === obj2); // => false
console.log(obj1 === obj1ref); // => true
```

Comment: I see now. Was thinking in that direction but haven't quite managed to get there. I appreciate your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sets stores object references and primitive values, so it compares values shallowly. The object references are seen as the same, while the objects them selves aren't compared for equality.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

For a true comparison use something like:

```
const deepEqual = (a,b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
```

Or make an array of unique object using something like:

```
const trueUnique = (arr) =>
      [...new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify))]
      .map(res => JSON.parse(res))
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I could use json.stringify to compare them but I'm looking for a more convenient method